# Installing Ansible Controllers to build agents which best practice to use?

Tags: ansible, azure-devops, appveyor, azure-pipelines

Trying to implement **infrastructure as code**. I need the ansible controller machine which pulls the updated playbooks from the git and run the playbooks to create the infrastructure. The issue is I have tried VSTS and AppVeyor and their build agents do not have Ansible installed.

Should I use my build agent for this task? I am looking for open source and free solutions for the open source project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infrastructure as code means that the infrastructure configuration is stored in a version control system (VCS). If changes will be applied, it is traceable who changed the code and when.

Although it is unclear to me what the aim is of your question, it is possible to use a continuous integration (CI) tool like, Jenkins, gitlab, circleci that pulls the code from git, installs ansible or use an image that contains ansible in order to run a playbook.

Comment: Hosted solutions don’t let us install custom software. I am now considering to use Kubernetes to have a holistic infrastructure. Also having the image ready could speed up the construction time.